# Git merge: why I saw some are "Merge branch 'master' of github.com:foo/bar", and some are "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'"?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote

Git merge: why I saw some are "Merge branch 'master' of github.com:foo/bar", and some are "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'"?

In my understanding, "merge" always merge remote tracking branch.

Comment: In short: you can merge any branch with any other branch. In git merge is just a commit with 2+ parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), the default merge message will include a reference to the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** and the branch being fetched then merged (like `github.com:foo/bar`).

If you do a [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), the default merge message will reference the **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)** name (like `origin/master`)

You can see the merge commit message being formed in [`builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c518059b263bb506b96a0ae90c4d40408c760cb0/builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c#L412-L457) of [`git fmt-merge-msg`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fmt-merge-msg).